# Git local branch auto merges

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge, branch

When i work on a git repo to do a quickfix i make a new local branch using `git checkout -b BRANCH_NAME` which makes the new branch i then work on that branch for a while and when im ready i do `git checkout dev` followed by `git merge BRANCH_NAME` to merge with the hotfix branch and i get the message `branch already up to date`.. which it shouldnt be because they are separate branches

This is bad because if something went wrong does that mean my dev branch would have already been updated? I have no idea why this is happening im still new to GIT so i would like for someone to explain what im doing wrong.

Comment: After doing some work on your `BRANCH_NAME` do you then `git add <...>` and `git commit -m "..."` ?

Comment: No i dont, i was using this tutorial by github:https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1

Wouldnt running 'git add - git commit -m' push it to the remote repo?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Let me add an answer. One minute please.

Comment: @e.doroskevic Just one more thing, the changes ive made were saved to the dev branch, why and how does this happen?

Comment: I will expand on the answer below

Comment: Also, I would highly recommend trying out [codeschool](https://www.codeschool.com/). They have 4 courses there covering `git`. The material is the best I have seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what happens is since you do not `add` and `commit` your changes. When you carry out merge your `dev` branch will be up-to-date since as far as `git` system is concerned the branch you've created is the same as `dev` branch (nothing has changed).

In order to get things done properly, what you need to do is do a bit of work on your branch then `add` all this work using

```
git add <filename>.<extension>
```

or if they are already tracked

```
git add .
```

This instruction will put the file into a *staging area*. Think of it as if you would prepare a back-pack. Sometimes you would want put some stuff in it and sometimes you would take stuff out of it.

Then commit the work using

```
git commit -m "Describe here what you've done"
```

This will basically take a snapshot of your *working directory* on your *local file system*. Think of it as if you just completed putting everything in your back-pack.

go to your master branch `dev`

```
git checkout dev
```

This will simply switch you to the branch you've specified. In this case it's `dev`

merge

```
git merge <branch>
```

*Note:* `<branch>` with whatever branch name you had been working on

Given you are on `dev` branch, this will merge the branch you are currently at (`dev`) with whatever branch you've specified in `<branch>` in the above instruction.